# Show console.log() in an HTML element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

I programmed a function, which writes all the stuff in the console (with `console.log(string);`).

Now I want to "simulate" or show the generated console log in a `<p>` or a `<div>`.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the clues in your question I take it you work in a browser environment.

`console` is an object on the `window` object. Therefor you can easily replace it. The following code will replace the browser's `window.console` with a custom `window.console` which has the method `log`. The `log` method will take a string and append it to an element with the id `myLog`

In your HTML:

```
<p id="myLog"></p>
```

In your JS:

```
window.console = {
  log: function(str){
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    document.getElementById("myLog").appendChild(node);
  }
}
console.log('hi');
console.log('there');
```

This is given that you only log *strings*. If you log other things, such as object, you probably want to add a type check in the `log` method and if it's an object, run it through [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) before adding it to the node.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It works. But if i try to run a big script, it don't works... This is tha script i wud like to run:  its from this website: [link]http://jsbin.com/kaluxuma/5/edit?js,console,output

Comment: The script you're linking to is using `console.clear` which you also need to replace. Extend the `window.console` with with a `clear` method and set it to clear your "myLog" element. E.g document.getElementById('myLog').innerHTML = "";

Comment: this does not work for array of objects, even with `JSON.stringify` the **<p>** displays only empty message

Answer (score 1):

HTLM:

```
<body>
  <ul id ="list"></ul>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function createMessage(str) {
  var newMessage = document.createElement('li').innerHTML = str;
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  list.insertBefore(newNode, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'some text that you send to the console...';
document.getElementById("thediv").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="thediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to just write to the page, you could use document.write(string).

Or, you could use paragraph tags and use document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a something like this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="yourContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function logToContainer (message) {
  var container = document.getElementById('yourContainer')
  var messageElement = document.createElement('p')
  messageElement.innerHtml = message
  container.appendChild(messageElement)
}
```

This gets the element with id `yourContainer`, creates a paragraph element then appends the paragraph to the container.

You could also use a `pre` block instead of the `p` if you wanted it to look more like the console output :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create a **single line** console with the **next log message overriding the previous one**, and each showing for a specific number of seconds, you can use something like this (that's what I use):

```js
console.log = (message) => {
  // wait until the console is clear to show next message
  function setMessage (_message) {
    if ($('#console').text()) {
      // if console is not empty, check again in 0.5s
      window.setTimeout(() => { setMessage(_message) }, 500)
    } else {
      $('#console').text(_message)
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        $('#console').text('')
      }, 3000) // shows the message for 3 seconds
    }
  }

  setMessage(message)
}

$('#button').click(()=>{
  console.log(Math.random().toString())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Generate random number on console</button>

<div id="console"></div>
```